# Why we write this, form = StudentForm(request.POST) in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is my views function,

```
def studentcreate(request):
    reg = StudentForm()
    string = "Give Information"

    if request.method == "POST":
        reg = StudentForm(request.POST)
        string = "Not Currect Information"

        if reg.is_valid():
            reg.save()
            return render('http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/')

    context = {
        'form':reg,
        'string': string,
    }

    return render(request, 'student.html', context)
```

Here first we store form in reg variable then also we write reg = StudentForm(request.POST) why?
acutally why we write this?

Comment: The first reg assignment is for all request methods other than POST. The second assignment is for POST requests. If POST, then it checks if the POST payload was valid and if so it saves a new instance to the db. The code from @Marco is mostly the same.

Comment: More precise: The first reg assignment is the general case, the second reg is the special case.

Comment: Good to ask. You probably shouldn't be. Put `reg = StudentForm()` in an else branch of that `if request.method == "POST"` to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you why you are writing this. Maybe only you know. It does not make much sense. I would recommend reading the Django documentation on this at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/#the-view

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

You read from data if the request is a POST. Otherwise, return an empty form.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of the "request.POST" as a parameter passed onto the form in the view. This tells the view that the form mentioned has POST data from the form in name.html. Otherwise it is just an empty form.